# Mock different api response based on input with Axios

Tags: javascript, mocking, axios

I'm building some e2e test for my Vuejs application.
The framework I'm using is Nightwatch along with the http library Axios (and the relative plugin for mocking: [Axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter)) and my current process is to have a file that intercepts all the api, and a file that return the reponse object:

So for example, if I want to mock `/api/sources`:

```
mock.onGet(/my.url\/api\/sources/).reply(() =>
  [200, ResponseObject.getSources],
);
```

And in the reponse object file I have:

```
const getSources = {
  files: [
    {
      id: 'bogus',
      fileName: 'bogus',
      fileUrl: 'http://bogus.com/1',
      size: 400,
      uploadedTime: '2018-05-24 10:56:27',
      sourceContact: 'boguscontact',
      isFolder: false,
    }, {
      id: 'bogus2',
      fileName: 'bogus 2',
      fileUrl: 'http://bogus.com/2',
      size: 500,
      uploadedTime: '2018-05-24 10:56:27',
      sourceContact: 'boguscontact',
      isFolder: false,
    }, {
      id: 'bogus3',
      fileName: 'bogus 3',
      fileUrl: 'http://bogus.com/3',
      size: 600,
      uploadedTime: '2018-05-24 10:56:27',
      sourceContact: 'boguscontact',
      isFolder: false,
    },
  ],
};
```

With this set up I have a very annoying problem:

Sometimes I have to return different object through the same api call, for example, if the file has a property `ready` and I want to test the user-flow to prepare a file to be ready I need to return the file with `ready: false` the first time, then I add some parameters, and then I have to return the file with `ready: true`. How can I do that?

Another example would be getting a single source file. I have the same api call `api/source/:sourceId` but when the source has `ready: true` it needs to have more parameters compare if the source has `ready: false`, but I don't know how to simulate that behaviour without a backend.

Right now the only thing I can do is to have a different response based on the query parameters:

```
mock.onGet(/dmd\.mocked\/api\/files/).reply((config) => {
  if (typeof config.params !== 'undefined') {
    switch (config.params.status) {
      case 'queued':
        return [200, ResponseObject.queuedFilesList];
      case 'processing':
        return [200, ResponseObject.processingFilesList];
      default:
        return [506];
    }
  } else {
    return [200, ResponseObject.queuedFilesList];
  }
});
```

but this approach works only if I make the call with different parameters. If I make the call without any parameters I don't know how to diversify the response.